# Adding a Foreign Key to an existing Table in supabase's PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I create two tables:

```
create table
exams (
exams_id bigint primary key generated always as identity,
name text,
created_at timestamptz default now()
);
```

and

```
create table
tutors (
tutors_id bigint primary key generated always as identity,
name text,
email text,
created_at timestamptz default now()
);
```

I then add the foreign key like this:

```
alter table
if exists public.exams 
add column tutor_id bigint;
```

and

```
alter table
if exists public.exams
add foreign key(tutor_id) references tutors(tutor_id);
```

The last command throws the following error:

```
column "tutor_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
```

Can someone tell me, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: i think you need a space between reserved word foreign key and the table name in parentheses `alter table
if exists public.exams
add foreign key (tutor_id) references tutors(tutor_id);`

Comment: thank you @zhiguang but this didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this was just some stupid misspelling causing problems.

Of course, the column 'tutors_id' of the 'tutors' table should be named 'tutor_id' instead.

Thank you for reading.